# Modal analysis with input sweep to obtain a transfer function

Tags: matlab

I want to obtain a transfer function from a mechanical structure. Therfore, I excite the structure with a sine sweep and measure with an acceleration sensor. Theoretically, I can obtain the transfer function with Matlab by using the following script:

```
fmin = 1;
fmax = 100;
tmax = 10;
deltaT = 0.01;
t=0:deltaT:tmax;
w=(fmin+(fmax-fmin)/tmax*t)*2*pi;
G = tf(0.5,[1 0.5]); % example transfer function
inp = 5*sin(w.*t);
out = lsim(G,inp,t); % is normally replaced by real measurements
figure; plot(t,inp,'r',t,out,'b');
data =iddata(out(:),inp(:),deltaT);
modfrd = etfe(data);
figure; bode(modfrd,G);
legend('Approximation','Real Curve');
```

But the results in reality are far away of being good (very noisy). Has anyone an idea how I can improve the conversion to a transfer function? Every hint would help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `tfestimate` but system identification is an art rather than science (despite what is constantly claimed).

```
[modfrd,w] = tfestimate(inp,out,[],256,512,100);
Gc = frd(modfrd,2*pi*w);
figure; bode(Gc,G);hold on;
legend('Approximation','Real Curve');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It improves the results slightly. But it is unfortunately not good enough. I think the main problem is that all these methods are dividing with a kind of fft of the input signal which is in my opinion not necessary. I thought they might have something for chirp signals in Matlab because sweeps are often used for acoustics.

Comment: @Sebastian Not really but I see what your concern is. Signal processing is actually the key point of the identification so you should pay more attention to that windowing settings. Also your input must be sufficiently rich, sys id people call this *persistence of excitation*. Here you can see your input is not rich enough (too short to start with and has only one principle frequency) . That's what I mean by an *art*